# Received error when trying to setChecked on Checkbox from different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has one Main Activity and is just composed of different fragments. In one fragment, after I got the JSON values from the server and try to set the check mark on the checkbox, the app crashes and I receive a

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object
>   reference

error I'm trying to set the checkbox value from a different fragment of where the checkbox value is.

Main Activity:

```
if(v == findViewById(R.id.login)){     //between fragments: from login screen to home page

        username_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_text);
        password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);;
        String signin = "http://acarjsystem.herokuapp.com/auth/";
        StringRequest request;

        uname = username_text.getText().toString();
        pword = password_text.getText().toString();

        final ProgressDialog loading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        loading.setTitle("Loading");
        loading.setMessage("Attempting to Log In");
        loading.show();
        ////////////////////
        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, signin, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                final Fragment nextFrag;
                final CheckBox check_locateCar, check_carOff,check_getImg, check_tase, check_carOn;
                try {
                    check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
                    check_carOff = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOff);
                    check_getImg = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_getImg);
                    check_tase = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_tase);
                    check_carOn = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOn);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jsonObject.getString("user").equals("logined")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("user"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                        if(!jsonObject.getString("car_plate").equals("0")){
                            loading.hide();

                            if(jsonObject.getString("car_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                //////////////HERE//////////////////////////////////
                                if(jsonObject.getString("loc_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                         /*THE ERROR IS AROUND THIS LINE*/
                                        check_locateCar.setChecked(true);
                                    }else{
                                        check_locateCar.setChecked(false);
                                    }
                                    if(jsonObject.getString("ignition").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                        check_carOff.setChecked(true);
                                    }else{
                                        check_carOff.setChecked(false);
                                    }
                                    if(jsonObject.getString("taser").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                        check_tase.setChecked(true);
                                    }else{
                                        check_tase.setChecked(false);
                                    }
                                    if(jsonObject.getString("photo_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                        check_getImg.setChecked(true);
                                    }else{
                                        check_getImg.setChecked(false);
                                    }

                                    //check_carOn.setChecked(false);
                                    nextFrag = new locate_updatedstatus();


                                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                }
                                else{

                                    loading.hide();
                                    nextFrag = new locate_before();
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                loading.hide();
                                nextFrag = new locate_car_reg();
                            }

                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            transaction.commit();


                        }else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("user"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loading.hide();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("username",username_text.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password",password_text.getText().toString());

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };


            requestQueue.add(request);

            ///////////////////////////
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,uname+"\n"+pword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //newFragment = new locate_login();
        }
```

fragment_locate_updatedstatus's XML file:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_locateCar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/updates"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Locate Car using Gmaps" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_carOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/check_locateCar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_locateCar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Turn car off" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_getImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_carOff"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/check_carOff"
        android:text="Capture images" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_tase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_getImg"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/check_getImg"
        android:text="Tase Culprit" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_carOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/check_tase"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_tase"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Turn system off" />
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Post your complete logs.. In which line u r getting that exception?

Comment: That is the complete error. The line where I get the error is here check_locateCar.setChecked(true);

Comment: I've also tried placing
check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
check_locateCar.setChecked(true); 
outside of the request line and the app crashes when the setChecked is placed but it runs alright when commented out.

Comment: "I'm trying to set the checkbox value from a different fragment of where the checkbox value is" Can you clarify? Is the main activity trying to set a fragments checkbox? Or, is a Fragment trying to set the Main Activity's checkbox, Or, is a Fragment trying to set another Fragment's checkbox?

Comment: The fragment containing these checkboxes isn't instantiated yet. That's why you're getting the null object reference.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, how could I solve that?

Comment: @anthony We already tried moving the fragment transaction to the top of the try block (before the findView statements, still crashed)... another answer below (if it doesn't solve this exact problem, it's standard practice anyway for fragment communication straight from googles docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: @GraceTanya I'm saying that you're trying reference checkboxes before they are created. That's why they are null. Ensure that the fragment is attached before you try grabbing references to the checkboxes. You could use a `Log` to write to the console where your error is above, and in the `onAttach` method of your fragment place another Log write. The Log in `onAttach` should write first.

Comment: @anthony I undeleted the post that trys this (see below).

Comment: @anthony Oh shoot, your right my answer wasn't quite right (update below).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your fragment transaction for `nextFrag':

```
if(v == findViewById(R.id.login)){     //between fragments: from login screen to home page

    username_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_text);
    password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);;
    String signin = "http://acarjsystem.herokuapp.com/auth/";
    StringRequest request;

    uname = username_text.getText().toString();
    pword = password_text.getText().toString();

    final ProgressDialog loading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    loading.setTitle("Loading");
    loading.setMessage("Attempting to Log In");
    loading.show();
    ////////////////////
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, signin, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            final Fragment nextFrag;
            final CheckBox check_locateCar, check_carOff,check_getImg, check_tase, check_carOn;
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if(jsonObject.getString("user").equals("logined")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("user"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                    if(!jsonObject.getString("car_plate").equals("0")){
                        loading.hide();

                        if(jsonObject.getString("car_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            //////////////HERE//////////////////////////////////

                                //check_carOn.setChecked(false);
                                nextFrag = new locate_updatedstatus();

                                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            }
                            else{

                                loading.hide();
                                nextFrag = new locate_before();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            loading.hide();
                            nextFrag = new locate_car_reg();
                        }

                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();

                        check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
                        check_carOff = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOff);
                        check_getImg = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_getImg);
                        check_tase = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_tase);
                        check_carOn = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOn);

                        if(jsonObject.getString("loc_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                             /*THE ERROR IS AROUND THIS LINE*/
                            check_locateCar.setChecked(true);
                        }else{
                            check_locateCar.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if(jsonObject.getString("ignition").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            check_carOff.setChecked(true);
                        }else{
                            check_carOff.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if(jsonObject.getString("taser").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            check_tase.setChecked(true);
                        }else{
                            check_tase.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if(jsonObject.getString("photo_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            check_getImg.setChecked(true);
                        }else{
                            check_getImg.setChecked(false);
                        }                           

                    }else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("user"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.hide();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("username",username_text.getText().toString());
                hashMap.put("password",password_text.getText().toString());

                return hashMap;
            }
        };


        requestQueue.add(request);

        ///////////////////////////
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,uname+"\n"+pword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //newFragment = new locate_login();
    }
```

Comment: It's still not working. The error is still the same as before. The checkboxes are defined in the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to set the checkbox value from a different fragment of where the checkbox value is.

Fragments need to communicate through the main/parent Activity via proxy. To do this

1. Define an interface for the listener method needed (in your case an OnCheckBoxSelectedListener listener).
2. Have the main Activity implement OnCheckBoxSelectedListener
3. Declare a private member of OnCheckBoxSelectedListener in your fragment(s)
4. In your Fragment's `onAttach` override set the OnCheckBoxSelectedListener member to the `Activity` argument.

   ---

1) Define an interface for the listener method needed (in your case an OnCheckBoxSelectedListener listener).

```
interface OnCheckBoxSelectedListener
{
    public void SetChecked(bool checked);
}
```

2) Have the main Activity implement OnCheckBoxSelectedListener

```
public class Activity implements OnCheckBoxSelectedListener
{
    public void SetCheck(bool checked)
    {
        check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
        check_locateCar.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

3) Declare a private member of OnCheckBoxSelectedListener in your fragment(s)
4) In your Fragment's `onAttach` override set the OnCheckBoxSelectedListener member to the `Activity` argument.

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnCheckBoxSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then from onResponse call the listener

```
      @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            final Fragment nextFrag;
            final CheckBox check_locateCar, check_carOff,check_getImg, check_tase, check_carOn;
            try {
                check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
                check_carOff = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOff);
                check_getImg = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_getImg);
                check_tase = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_tase);
                check_carOn = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_carOn);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if(jsonObject.getString("user").equals("logined")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("user"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                    if(!jsonObject.getString("car_plate").equals("0")){
                        loading.hide();

                        if(jsonObject.getString("car_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            //////////////HERE//////////////////////////////////
                            if(jsonObject.getString("loc_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                     /*THE ERROR IS AROUND THIS LINE*/
                                    //check_locateCar.setChecked(true);
                                    mListener.SetChecked(true)
                                }else{
                                    check_locateCar.setChecked(false);
                                }
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Note:** The above establishes communication in the direction of Fragment to Activity. To go the other way (a "callback" from the listener), I define a callback interface, implement it in the Fragment, and call it from the listener using a reference to the Fragment passed in as an argument (via the `this` pointer). For example

```
interface OnCheckBoxSelectedListener
{
    public void SetCheck(OnCheckBoxSelectedCallback callingFragment, attachmentDialog2EventListener, bool checked);
}

interface OnCheckBoxSelectedCallback
{
    SetCheckedCallback();
}

public class Activity implements OnCheckBoxSelectedListener
{
    public void SetCheck(OnCheckBoxSelectedCallback callingFragment, bool checked)
    {
        check_locateCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_locateCar);
        check_locateCar.setChecked(true);

        callingFragment.SetCheckedCallback();
    }
}

public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment implements OnCheckBoxSelectedCallback {
    OnCheckBoxSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnCheckBoxSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCheckBoxSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...

    public void SetCheckedCallback()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It would then be called from onRequest as follows (you may not need a callback in this case, but at some point you probably will, like when startActivityForRequest/onActivityRequest are called from Main Activity, since they run on separate thread)

```
      @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // ...
                            if(jsonObject.getString("loc_stat").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                     /*THE ERROR IS AROUND THIS LINE*/
                                    //check_locateCar.setChecked(true);
                                    mListener.SetChecked(this, true)
                                }else{
                                    check_locateCar.setChecked(false);
                                }
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wait give me time to try this

Comment: Take your time. You should become very familiar with this step, I wouldn't gloss it... Not sure if/how things change with sub-fragments yet.

Comment: @GraceTanya Please try my original, updated answer below.

Comment: The line mListener.SetChecked(true); show Cannot Resolve Symbol message.

Comment: I named it `SetCheck` by mistake in the interface definition, try renaming it accordingly.

Comment: You should also try the updated answer below (it's just a refactor, no new code added).